# What does "SAWarning: transaction already deassociated from connection" mean?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How does an SQLAlchemy transaction get deassociated from a connection?  What should I do to prevent that?

Comment: Unfortunately reducing the code to a simple example is probably about as hard as answering this question myself.  So I'm hoping somebody already knows what it means :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This warning is issued when SQLAlchemy tries to roll back a transaction, or a savepoint, which has already been rolled back.  For example:

```py
>>> import sqlalchemy as sa
>>> engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///', echo=True, future=True)
>>> with engine.connect() as conn:
...     with conn.begin() as txn:
...         txn.rollback()
...         txn.rollback()
...
```

outputs

```
2021-06-12 15:13:13,669 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2021-06-12 15:13:13,669 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
<stdin>:4: SAWarning: transaction already deassociated from connection
```

You can see the two related unit tests [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/c2cad1f97c51c8a2a6ad5d371ece7bcd9c7ffcf9/test/engine/test_transaction.py#L269).